# Assign the results of SQL query to variable in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to get the result of a sql query(which is already in another variable) to a variable

Below is the first dynamic sql which I am executing to get the result to @sqlquery variable

```
DECLARE @ID = 1,
@vquery NVARCHAR(1000),
@sqlquery NVARCHAR(1000)

SET @vquery = N'SELECT @sqlquery = sqlquery FROM table1 WHERE ID = '+@ID

EXEC sp_executesql @vquery, @Params = N'@sqlquery NVARCHAR(1000) OUTPUT, @ID INT',@sqlquery = @sqlquery OUT, @ID = @ID

PRINT @sqlquery
```

output

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2
```

My next step(continuation to above code) is to get the result of above query which is in @sqlquery variable to different variable(@countresult)

Below is the code I have tried

```
DECLARE 
@countresult INT

SET @sqlquery = @sqlquery

EXEC sp_executesql @sqlquery, @Params = N'@countresult INT OUTPUT',@countresult = @countresult OUT

PRINT @countresult
```

I am not getting the result of the query to variable instead its executing the query and displaying the results in tabular format

Note: I am not able to assign the variable(@countresult) to count(*) in dynamic sql because this query is fetched from table1

Comment: That first query will error, '... ID = '+@ID` will result in a conversion error. Why are you trying to injecting the value, rather than parameterising it?

Comment: I take it you've considered the case & are fine with the option for someone to insert `SHUTDOWN WITH NOWAIT` as their dynamic query in `table1`? What about queries that don't return a single row with a single `INT` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the query is SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table, there's no easy way to output it's value to a variable.

What you can do is to wrap this query into a following construct:

SELECT @count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table)

This way you can output it. But it will not work for all kinds of queries. But that's life, and this whole thing is a bad idea.

Your whole dynamic code would look something like:

```sql
DECLARE @ID = 1,
@vquery NVARCHAR(1000),
@sqlquery NVARCHAR(1000)

SET @vquery = N'SELECT @sqlquery = sqlquery FROM table1 WHERE ID = '+CAST(@ID AS NVARCHAR(MAX))

EXEC sp_executesql @vquery, @Params = N'@sqlquery NVARCHAR(1000) OUTPUT, @ID INT',@sqlquery = @sqlquery OUT, @ID = @ID

PRINT @sqlquery

DECLARE 
@countresult INT

SET @sqlquery = 'SELECT @countresult = (' + @sqlquery + ')'

EXEC sp_executesql @sqlquery, @Params = N'@countresult INT OUTPUT',@countresult = @countresult OUT

PRINT @countresult
```